# Need assistancce with c++ sytem() functionn

Tags: c++, system

ok so i wrote a program which scaans all directories an sub directories to find sepcific file extensions(i pass a string for the extension type i want) then it returns a vector loade with all the filenames with the specific filetype extensions. then i have another class which has a function that print out all of the files in the vector and will then will iterate the vector and run a program in that vector that the user chooses. This is my problem. Getting the file from the vvector to run. i am using visual studios on windows 7
 using boost filesystem V3. this is my current function:

```
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED

#ifndef NotePad__h
#define NotePad__h

#include boost/filesystem.hpp
#include iostream
#include io.h
#include stdlib.h
#include stdio.h
#include cstdlib
#include Windows.h
#include atlstr.h
#include string
#include cstring
;
namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

class NpLaunch 
{
public:
    void Launch (const std::vector<fs::path>& v)
    {
        int count=0;
        std::cout << "launched in notePad.h" << std::endl;
        for(auto i = v.begin(); i!= v.end(); ++i)
        {
            //string s;
            //string val = (string) itr;
            std::cout << count << ". " << *i << std::endl;
            ++count;
            std::string s = i->c_str();
            //std::system(i->c_str());
        }
    }

};

#endif
```

and this is the error im getting:

> Error  1   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const >boost::filesystem3::path::value_type *' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' >c:\users\admin\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\launcher\launcher\notepad.h   31

Comment: wanted to know whether if should do a static cast if tht that would work. not looking for answer but hints/tips

Comment: Just a guess, try wstring instead of string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows, `path::value_type` is a `wchar_t`, and thus `path::string_type` is equivilent to `std::wstring`, and the `path::c_str()` method returns a `wchar_t*`.  You cannot assign a `wchar_t*` to a `std::string`, that is what the compiler error is trying to tell you.

To assign a `path` object to a `std::string`, you have to perform a character conversion from `wchar_t` to `char`. The `path::string()` method does that for you, eg:

```
std::string s = i->string();
```

Otherwise, use a `std::wstring` instead, which you can assign to using either the `path::native()` or `path::wstring()` method, eg:

```
std::wstring s = i->native(); 

std::wstring s = i->wstring();
```

Comment: thank you, but i fugred it out about 2 minutes after i posted this hahah but thanks anyways